# Term for Internet or Texting Acronyms, e.g. LOL, IMHO, M8

Tags: acronyms, internet

What are the acronym, internet words like lol, brb, imho, etc., called? Is there such a term beyond acronym? I was wanting to tell someone that someone else was not familiar with the *meme*/*internet* *jargon*/*acronym* 'M8' (or mate), but couldn't think of a reasonable word to use.

So, is there a term that would define these terms for how they are different than other, regular english 'SMS text'. Moreover, we find these terms more and more in the wild and not necessarily even on electronic devices, like on t-shirts or even spoken.

If I e-mail the message, "I'll be leaving the office at 10, but then I'll brb."  What would I call the 'brb' part of the message, apart from the rest? "He e-mailed his boss a message saying 'He'd be right back', but he decided using an [*internet* *jargon*] was acceptable."

---

Update 02/01/2018

Although I have accepted an answer for now, I think it is inadequate, and that a word will eventually be coined to define these text terms. Until then...

Comment: This page calls it Internet Slang: http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words04/usage/slang_internet.html . This page calls it "Typical texting language" or an "initialism": http://blog.dictionary.com/texting-leet/

Comment: Why do you think that "but he decided that using chat speak was acceptable" isn't a valid statement? That's exactly what I'd say... though I'd be more likely to say "I find your use of chat speak in emails disturbing."

Comment: Well, I think that's a good question. So, I would know what you mean, but that sounds to me like 'street speak', instead of the more specific thought, using a slang word. So, 'text term' or 'chat term' is getting a little closer. And it's becoming clear there really is no single word for it.

Comment: Obligatory [initialism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initialism) comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, it's called "chat speak" or "text speak" as it originated in shorthand used when writing text messages and in chat rooms on the internet.

The main Wikipedia article calls it [SMS language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) but I've never heard that term before.

> SMS language or textese (also known as txt-speak, txtese, chatspeak, txt, txtspk, txtk, txto, texting language, txt lingo, SMSish, txtslang, txt talk) is a term for the abbreviations and slang commonly used with mobile phone text messaging, but sometimes used with other Internet-based communication such as email and instant messaging.

The Wikipedia article includes [lists of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language#Whole_word_or_phrase_abbreviation) that include the ones you've listed in your question.

Another source of information, [NetLingo.com](http://www.netlingo.com/acronyms.php) broadens the terms for this to include:

> a.k.a. Internet acronyms, text message jargon, abbreviations, initialisms, cyberslang, leetspeak, SMS code, textese

Note that [leetspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet) (or just leet) is generally considered a separate entity from chat/text speak, as it uses more numerals and special suffixes and also encompasses things like ASCII art.

LOL, notably, has its own Wikipedia article where it is defined as being internet slang:

> LOL or lol, an acronym for laugh(ing) out loud, or lots of laughs, is a popular element of Internet slang. It was first used almost exclusively on Usenet, but has since become widespread in other forms of computer-mediated communication and even face-to-face communication. It is one of many initialisms for expressing bodily reactions, in particular laughter, as text, including initialisms for more emphatic expressions of laughter such as LMAO ("laugh(ing) my ass off") and ROFL (or its older form ROTFL; "roll(ing) on the floor laughing"). Other unrelated expansions include the now mostly obsolete "lots of luck" or "lots of love" used in letter-writing.

Comment: **SMS** = *Short Message Service*, for anyone who's wondering. (I was, so I looked it up.)

Comment: So, these are descriptors for 'text speak'. That would lead me to believe that the word I'd be looking for, if it existed, which it appears does not, would be a word that is nearly synonymous with 'text term'. Text speak, text term, both convey the general idea that it is via text, but not necessarily that it is either a term that translates to an entire phrase, or shortening of one. I'm going to update my question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, TIL!

Comment: @rand al'thor: Ditto! Being an ole fart, I had to look up ***TIL*** too, so I've actually learned *two* things today. (The bummer being that at my age I'll prolly have forgotten *both* of them by tomorrow! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It always amazes me how much usage varies on this—you've got parts of the Anglosphere where no one even has a clue what SMS means, and then you've got parts where “I'll SMS you” is the regular thing to say and ‘text’ would raise eyebrows and cause confusion. And then of course the majority of the Anglosphere where ‘text’ is more common but SMS is equally well understood.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet interesting point. I know what an SMS is... though I'd be hard pressed to have known what the acronym meant but I'd be unlikely to use the term... Since I use Apple devices, I tend to use "message" or "text" when referring to SMS messages.

Comment: @Janus: I've always found it odd how many Americans still talk about ***cellphones***. Why would anyone *care* about the fact that the network topology is organized into cells? Unless the early cells weren't reasonably contiguous, in which case they wouldn't be very usable anyway. At least terms like ***mobile*** and ***text*** are "transparent" (in context) to ordinary people. Allowing the geeks to promote terms like ***cell*** and ***SMS*** just because from their blinkered perspective they seem "relevant" for the new technology doesn't seem like such a good idea to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't even know why, but I've always instinctively understood the cells in cellphones to refer to phone masts—I've never associated it with network topology aside from the fact that cell phones need a cell (mast) to give them signal. I'll admit that the first time I heard someone say “I'll text you”, I didn't understand what they meant—I thought they were talking about e-mailing. It's a unilaterally transparent term, at least, which is one lateral more than SMS has going for it.

Comment: @Janus: I suppose I must have seen phone masts, but I've never taken much notice of them. And it's TIL ***3*** for me today to find out that you'd call a mast a "cell". When I mentioned "wifi hotspots" to my daughter a couple of weeks ago she said *"Dad!* It's more a matter of whether you're in a wifi ***cold spot**!"* The times they are a-changing. (And yes, I ***do*** mean that as an allusion to the shit going down in Turkey right now! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Honestly, I have no idea whether you _would_ call a phone mast a cell—it's just the association I've always made in my head, right or wrong or even completely nonsensical.

Comment: @Catija, I have a real gut feeling that we will have a single word someday for these terms. Until then yours is probably the best that we have. Accepting this. Thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (and JanusBahsJacquet) I can definitely say that from the mountainous rurals of Pennsylvania the "Cell" metaphor is still highly relevant. You drive around here for a while and you can really visualize the coverage areas as large amoeba-like zones centered around the nucleus of a cell base (tower). If you know the area well enough you can predict within 50ft where you'll lose a call.

Comment: @H.R.Rambler: Since it's 18 months since the original comments were posted, I just glanced through them to remind myself of the context. The ***real*** bummer of which is that [*I just had to look up "TIL" **again**!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337455/term-for-internet-or-texting-acronyms-e-g-lol-imho-m8/337456?noredirect=1#comment775435_337456) Still, looking on the bright side there's always a chance I might remember it this time! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ha! Life is one heck of an adventure, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread because, I too wanted to know the name for this category of terms. I can't believe there isn't one yet; at least not any that ***I*** would want to be stuck with for the rest of eternity.

So let's come up with a term for this type of abbreviated text.

I propose "**TLA**". This stands for "**T**hree **L**etter **A**cronyms" of course.

Before a bunch of people reply with a lot of irrelevant points like, "Wait! TLA like "ROFLMAO" has more than three letters!", I would counter with, "Who cares. it doesn't have to make sense. It just has to sound better than "SMS speak" (which, BTW, we can all agree is just terrible, right?)

But if that argument falls flat, then I was mistaken, WHat I meant to say is the **TLA** stands for "**T**ext **L**etter **A**cronyms"

If that doesn't work, then come up with something better and post it here

(aside: I saw John's comment to Catija:

> @Catija, I have a real gut feeling that we will have a single word someday for these terms. Until then yours is probably the best that we have. Accepting this. Thanks. – John Jul 22 '16 at 16:13

after I posted. I reread Catija's post, however, and wasn't really able to discern what term was being accepted. Perhaps Catija or John could clarify what term they are proposing. Sorry if I stepped on any toes.

Comment: Her answer was "chat" or "text" - "speak", so... I'm not crazy about it. I do think the question has value and I'm glad you were able to find it in your queries. I can't really vote yours as an answer, but I think it's a good proposition. And I do like where you're going with it. Another proposition might be "AT"s for Abbreviated Texts. It has the added benefit of being the name for a symbol that is common in electronic communications - The @! "The young woman had included all kinds of 'at's in the text to her boss"

Comment: To comment further on the 'at' proposal, Because using 'at' for the purpose of an e-mail address is almost always in the context of dictating an e-mail address, it's reuse should not be (IMO) ambiguous or confusing. Kind of like, "her response was full of 'buts'" would not be interpreted as she only used the word "but".